# How to restore a .sql.gz dump on a Docker MySQL instance?

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a dump which was taken from a machine on which Docker is NOT installed. The format is .sql.gz - my question is how do I restore this on my Docker MySQL instance?

Able to access MySQL from command line:

```
docker run -it --link first-mysql:mysql --rm mysql sh -c 'exec mysql -h"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR" -P"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT" -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"'
```

NOT able to restore the dump using this:

docker exec -i first-mysql mysql -uroot -ppassword < db_dump.sql

Answer (score 2):

Basic syntax is:

```
gunzip dump.sql.gz
docker exec -i container_name mysql -uroot -proot < dump.sql
```

Or copy dunp.sql into a volume go into the conatainer and start mysql there

```
docker exec -ti container_name bash
mysql < /volume_dir/dump.sql
```

The rest in mysql syntax.

Comment: The basic syntax is not working. I am getting 'access denied' if I do that.

Comment: If the error comes from mysql provide `-u uername -p password` parameters. But that is basic mysql syntax.

Comment: Yes, but it is not working. It says 'access denied'. I know it is basic mysql syntax :)

Comment: Get into the docker and see how you can connect to mysql. I Have had a lot of trouble connecting to mysql in docker because of anonymous users. Drop them in the mysql database create script. `mysql -uroot -e "DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user='';"`  `mysql -uroot -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;";`

Comment: Yes, I just saw your comment.

Answer (score 1):

1. Because logging in from root wasn't an issue, log into MySQL using root.
2. Create another user with all the privileges, a kind of equivalent to root.
3. Flush privieleges.

> docker exec -i container_name mysql -uloader -ploader < dump.sql

Answer (score 0):

This is strong text a very simple problem that should be looked at superficially.

1. Your existing  is this backup_2023_07_05T10_10_04.sql.gz backup.
2. `docker start` You can find it through this command `docker ps -a` . It usually looks like this d23d4fg5g5g6h7
3. `docker exec -ti container_name bash` . It usually looks like this
   root@d23d4fg5g5g6h7:/#
4. root@b774def4184d:/# `restore backup_2023_07_05T10_10_04.sql.gz`.Don't forget to change backup name to your bacup name.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQvDK.png)

if it works it will look like this